# min in inline assembly in gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, sse

As for today i used my own `min()` function (for `float` and `int`)
that was based on if but today as i get know that x86 has some operand
for min - this is

> MINSS - Minimum of operands

i think that if based `min()` routine is counter effective and
im very careful for optimization, so i would like rewrite my own
routine into `minss` version with some inline assembly,

I would like to find how the most effective version of this in 
gcc inline assembly would look like

I need something like

```
int min(int a, int b)
{
  // minss a, b
   //return 
}
```

for both `int` and `float`, to use `minss` opcode and has minimal prologue and 
epilogue

or just using library version would be faster? though i would like 
to not use library min/max and had it as much fast if possible

Comment: I think just using sse-enable flag of compiler is much better. Compiler knows far more information than us.

Comment: I don't know why this question get 2 downvote. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the most efficient possible implementation of `min` for `int`s and `float`s:

```
int
min_int(int a, int b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

float
min_float(float a, float b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

"But," you exclaim, "those will have conditional jumps in them!"  Nope.  Here's the output of `gcc -S -O2`:

```
min_int:
    cmpl    %edi, %esi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    cmovle  %esi, %eax
    ret

min_float:
    minss   %xmm1, %xmm0
    ret
```

For `int`s you get a conditional move, and for `float`s you get `minss`, because the compiler is very smart.  No inline ASM needed!

EDIT: If you're still curious about how to do it with inline assembly, here's an example (for gcc):

```
float
min_float_asm(float a, float b)
{
  float result = a;
  asm ("minss %1, %0" : "+x" (result) : "x" (b));
  return result;
}
```

The `x` constraint means "any SSE register", and `"+x"` means the value will be read and written, whereas `"x"` means read-only.

Comment: @user2214913 I've added an example.

Comment: In your inline assembly, should both `result` and `b` be both in input-list and in output-list? They're used as *r/w*..

Comment: The source operand for `minss` can be memory or register, so you could use `"xm" (b)` to give the compiler the option.  (But clang sometimes spills to memory for no reason with constraints like that.)

Comment: True, but if you want the compiler to optimize the code better, just do `return a < b ? a : b;` :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest against such micro-optimization. If you want to do it anyway, GCC has some `__builtin_*` functions. One is [`v4sf __builtin_ia32_minss (v4sf, v4sf)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html#X86-Built-in-Functions). There are other `min*` built-ins as well, check the docs.

#### Update

To gain more portability, you might want to take a look at the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).  Those functions are usually supported by GCC and Clang as well.

Comment: know intrinsics a bit but asked about inline assembly

Comment: @user2214913: I think this is an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), hence my suggesting either a complete avoidance of this micro-optimization or use of intrinsic functions.